# PowerPivot dashboard no data - Last successful refresh run: The cube has not been processed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-services, powerpivot

I used AutoSPInstaller to install my farm, I then installed PowerPivot 2012 and configured with the following script:

```
# Open PowerShell library from: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerPivotTools\ConfigurationTool\Resources\ConfigurePowerPivot.ps1
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerPivotTools\ConfigurationTool\Resources\PowerPivotFarm.wsp'
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerPivotTools\ConfigurationTool\Resources\PowerPivotWebApp.wsp'
DeployFarmSolution
DeployWebAppSolutionToCentralAdmin
Install-SPFeature -path PowerPivot
Install-SPFeature -path PowerPivotAdmin
Install-SPFeature -path PowerPivotSite
SetEngineServiceCredentials 'mydomain\SQL_PowerPivot' $password_PowerPivot; New-PowerPivotEngineServiceInstance -Provision:$true
New-PowerPivotSystemServiceInstance -Provision:$true
New-PowerPivotServiceApplication -ServiceApplicationName 'Default PowerPivot Service Application' -DatabaseServerName 'sharepoint' -DatabaseName 'SPA_DefaultPowerPivotServiceApplicationDB' -AddToDefaultProxyGroup:$true;Set-PowerPivotSystemService -WorkbookUpgradeOnDataRefresh:$False -Confirm:$false
DeployWebAppSolution 'http://intranet.mydom.local/' 2047
EnableSiteFeatures 'http://intranet.mydom.local' $true
CreateUnattendedAccountForDataRefresh 'http://intranet.mydom.local' 'PowerPivotUnattendedAccount' 'PowerPivot Unattended Account for Data Refresh' 'mydomain\SP_PowerPivotRefresh' $password_PowerPivotRefresh 
AddMSOLAP5AsECSTrustedProvider 'Excel Services Application'
```

I then logged into the Central Administration and went to the PowerPivot console where I received a wonderfully descriptive message 'Excel : An error has occured'.

I found this to be due to the application pool under which the Excel service runs did not have owner rights on the AdminContent database, providing db_owner rights to AdminContent database fixed this.

Ahtough I no longer get the Excel error pop up when entering the PowerPivot dashboard, I get no data and can see the status `Last successful refresh run: The cube has not been processed!`.

The same occurs even if I manually start the timed jobs, no dice.

I am following the [PowerPivot install guide here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210609)

Advice appreciated otherwise it will be time to get on the phone to Microsoft and pay for their support.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue. What ended up helping me was modifying the the odc connection file from 'MSOLAP' to 'MSOLAP.5' as well as the connection properties on the Server Health.xlsx and the Work Activity.xlsx . That fixed up the issue with no data appearing and the subsequent refresh of data does not error out. This have 'The cube has not processed but I can see data now. I think that message will clear out after the timer job runs again but not sure. Good thing is I have data now.

Comment: The cube now processes. I modified my timer job and now is refreshing properly.